# Download PDF from behind a log-in page

Tags: pdf, download, automation

I need to download a PDF behind a log-in page on a scheduled basis.

Manually, the process is:

1. Log in
2. Select drop-down
3. Download PDF

Is there any way to automate this process on a Mac?

Comment: There are better people than me to answer Mac questions, so I wont try to answer.  However, this just sounds like a business process to me.  Sure there are ways to automate it, but it feels like a change in procedure would be a better choice.  Talk to the people who provide the PDF, be it your IT dept or vendor and ask them if there is a way to streamline the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is a way, automator is a application native to Mac which can "automate" the process for you.

I have done this before but cant seem to find the link i used, however it is pretty stragiht forward.

Check out [Mac OSX Automator Download](http://internet.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-mac-os-x-automator-download-internet-files-251724/)